# get data from field database

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

i want to ask

i have field example name of field is "orders" and in field orders have data like this (this field on phpmyadmin)

```
========
orders
======== 
{email":"tst@gmail.com","name":"myname","phone":"+123123123"}
```

how to get the data email, name, and phone?

in normal script to get data from field, example email like this :

```
<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
```

but how to get the data if the contents of the field like that?

please help me,

thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What datatype does the field have? `json`, `varchar` or `text`? If it's `json`, you can extract it in your query, otherwise, you need to manually do a `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to access the values like array like this:

```
<td>'.$row['email'].'</td>
```

You should convert your data into array first, and then you can use it as array:

```
$json = json_decode($row['orders'], true);  // 2nd argument `true` converts json object into array.
$email = $json['email'];
```

Or you can directly print inside HTML tags:

```
<td>'.$json["email"].'</td>
```

So, If you have more fields:

```
=========
country
=========
{"id":"001","country:"english","code:"123123"}

$order_json = json_decode($row['orders'], true);
$email = $order_json['email'];
$country_json = json_decode($row['country'], true);
$country = $country_json['country'];
```

Comment: Hi Sir @Himansu Upadhyay sorry ask again, how to get data from 2 fields in json?thank you before

Comment: Can you explain how 2 fields?

Comment: scroll to bottom sir, i explain to 2 fields

Comment: Well, @creat15, you should create this as a new question.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it. It has the answer of your 2nd question.

Comment: thank you sir for help, but i try not works sir,thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored in json. so you can use `json_decode()`

```
$json = json_decode($row['orders']);
$email = $json->email;
```

Comment: hi sir, thank you for help me, i will try like this 
<td>'.$json = json_decode($row['email']);$pm_nama = $json->email;.'</td> not work sir